# C++, structure database program issues

Tags: c++, function, comparison, structure, conditional-statements

I apologize if this is in the wrong place. I didn't really see an area where to post specific code problems.

I'm tasked by my professor to create a program that allows a user to insert, edit and print out a database of clients. I'm having a problem with one of my functions, it doesn't seem to be comparing something well. The function is the `EditClient` function on line 85, the logic problem I'm having is on line 93. I included a few tests in the code that makes me certain it is line 93, for example in the else statement on line 99 I have it printing out the same arguments being used in the comparison. Which works! I'm clueless as to why it's not understanding the comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


struct ClientInfo{ // the structure template for the client info
    char name[40]; //client name
    char state[40]; //client state
    char city[40];
    int PhoneNumber;
    long double AccountBalance; //accounts balance
    char PaymentDate; //payment date

};

ClientInfo ClientList[10]; //intializes an array with the data type clientinfo


void MainMenu();

void NewClient(ClientInfo List[]); // prototypes
void ViewClient(ClientInfo List[]);
void EditClient(ClientInfo List[]);
int main(){

    MainMenu();
    system("pause");
}


void MainMenu(){ //this function is the main menu function
    char choice = 4;
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop){
        cout << "Welcome to the client database, enter 1 to view the clients, 2 to edit a client , and 3 to enter an entire new client. 0 to quit" << endl; //main menu prompt
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == '1'){
            ViewClient(ClientList);
        }
        else if (choice == '2'){
            EditClient(ClientList);
        }
        else if (choice == '3'){
            NewClient(ClientList);
        }
        else if (choice == '0'){
            cout << "thank you for using the client database, closing out now" << endl;
            loop = false;
        }
        else{
            cout << "invalid number" << endl;

        }
    }
}


void NewClient(ClientInfo List[]){//function that goes through cins to insert client data

        int desiredTimes = 0; // the number of clients the person wish to enter
        cout << "how many clients are you entering ?, your list current has "<<endl;
        cin >> desiredTimes;
        cout << "entering new client function..." << endl;
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < desiredTimes; cnt++){ // runs the program exactly the amount of times the person wished.
                cout << "please enter client name" << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(List[cnt].name, 40);
                cout << "please enter client state" << endl; // the getline is used here because there may be spacings within these first 3 catagories 
                cin.getline(List[cnt].state, 40);
                cout << "please enter client city" << endl;
                cin.getline(List[cnt].city, 40);
                cout << "please enter client Phone Number" << endl;
                cin.ignore(); // this is used to prevent the getline from causing issues with the cin
                cin >> List[cnt].PhoneNumber;
                cout << "please enter client Account Balance" << endl;
                cin >> List[cnt].AccountBalance;
                cout << "please enter client Payment Date" << endl;
                cin >> List[cnt].PaymentDate;
            }

}

void EditClient(ClientInfo List[]){ // function to search for a name requested and display the info
    char name[40];
    cout << "what is the name of the client you wish to view (be specific)?";
    cin >> name;
    bool loop = true; // boolean for the loop
    int cnt = 0; // position in the array
    while (loop){

        if (cnt < 11){
            if (name == List[cnt].name){ //if true, prints out the client's info
                cout << "true";
                /*NewClient(List[cnt]);*/
                loop = false; // ends the loop
            }

            else{
                cout << name << " " << List[cnt].name << endl;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "your client isn't in the database M8" << endl;
            loop = false;
        }
    }


}







void ViewClient(ClientInfo List[]){//this function goes through the client list and displays a particular client
    cout << "the following is a huge overrun of all the data inside this list, prepare your self." << endl;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= 10; cnt++){//goes through until the counter is greater than the size of the list in the parameter 
        cout << endl;
        cout << List[cnt].name;
        cout << List[cnt].state;
        cout << List[cnt].city;
        cout << List[cnt].PhoneNumber;
        cout << List[cnt].AccountBalance;
        cout << List[cnt].PaymentDate;

    }
}
```

this is the specific line, where i'm having a comparision error.

```
if (name == List[cnt].name){ //if true, prints out the client's info
```

Comment: For future reference, don't use line numbers when referring to code without line numbers. I didn't down-vote this question.

Comment: for those wanting the output, after succesfully inserting a client using the newclient function. I will enter a name, lets say bob.

output:

bob bob
bob
bob
bob
bob
bob
bob
bob
bob

Comment: @JonnyHenly Sorry about that, i'll edit the question to include line numbers

Comment: I would avoid line numbers all together and instead stick to explaining the problem using code snippets and program output matched with desired output.

Comment: @JonnyHenly i couldn't find an option to insert a sniplet for standard console output. Uploading an image was not a solution either, because of my low reputation. But i did pull out the exact line i'm having a problem with.   Thanks for the heads up on a proper way of asking a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I meant pieces of your code snipped from context, not inserting a code snippet : ) Code snippets are for `html`, `javascript` and `css`. That was my fault, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (name == List[cnt].name)` is doing a pointer comparison, not a string comparison.  This will only be true if `name` and `List[cnt].name` point to the same memory location, which they never will.  You should probably be using `std::string` instead of `char[]`, but if you need to use `char[]` for some reason, you'll need to use the [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) function to compare them.

Comment: thank you very much for explaining in detail how the strcmp function works! This solved me problem, i appreciate it :).

Answer (score 0):

instead of the if statement you are using, trying using this statement,

```
 if (strcmp(name,List[cnt].name)==0){
```

It should work properly :)

Comment: thank you so much! :) I wish i could upvote you but apparently i need reputation for that too. Guess i better start answering questons